# Multiple Time series aggregation in SQL / Big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to have a single table with multiple time series aggregations. For example, in this table,

user_id,date,conversions

1,11/08/2022,3

2,11/08/2022,1

Is it possible to have a single SQL query to generate a table like below :

user_id, conversions_last_7_days, conversions_last_30_days

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

We can use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT
    user_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN "date" BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND
               CURRENT_DATE() THEN conversions ELSE 0 END) AS conversions_last_7_days,
    SUM(CASE WHEN "date" BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND
               CURRENT_DATE() THEN conversions ELSE 0 END) AS conversions_last_30_days
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user_id;
```